# State transition tables - how to derive test cases reliabily?

Tags: testing, transition

I have a state-chart describing our system and I need to produce test cases covering all transitions.
As an example, take the following one state-transition table:

CS=Current State, IN=Input, NextS=next state

```
CS  IN  NextS
s61 e71 s18
s61 e94 s61
s18 e71 s65
s18 e94 s19
s19 e71 s19
s19 e94 s19
s65 e71 s61
s65 e94 s18
```

Now when I need to generate tests covering the complete path, it is quite error prone:

One Test case covering one possible path (e.g. going through states) 
S61 - E71 - S18
S18 - E71 - S65
S65 - E71 - S61

then of course I must create the rest when the other input is used, e.g.:
S61 - E71 - S18
S18 - E71 - S65
S65 - E94 - S18

But it is very difficult to keep track of covered scenarios. Is there any formal/known technique that would make it easier?

Comment: Do you really need the complete path test if you have the tests of each particular transition separately?

Comment: Of course a complete path is required, tests for individual states are easy but most issue arise along the path

Comment: It is about a technique which would yield combinations of inputs and states ensuring the coverage of all paths. It cannot be simplified, it is already simple